# Finding the derivative and stationary point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I had no idea how to attempt this question, but i came across a recap of a lecture and i kinda followed it through. I don't exactly know what i've done as it was really easy to substitute their numbers for mine.

Given the function
$$f(x)=\ln(x^2−2x+2)$$

a) Compute the derivative $f′(x)$

b) Find and classify the stationary point of $f(x)$

[my answer](http://vvcap.net/db/o-i3LxnYzJOoqtr23a-_.htp)

if the answer should be like this then i could just memorise it for the exam and that should be fine, doubt it is correct though ;p

Comment: dunno why it's coming up with .htp the link is http://vvcap.net/db/o-i3LxnYzJOoqtr23a-_.htp

Comment: this link is a bit suspicious, I would not click on it. Can you just type briefly what results you got? Use $ on both ends of a math formula and \ln for ln, x^2 for x^2 inside..

Comment: If you go on my past questions i've used this link for all :P it's a legit site, search it up on google... I've drawn it out on paint and just printscreened it and put it on web..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you calculated the derivative correctly.

$$f(x)=\ln(x^2−2x+2)\implies f'(x) = \dfrac {2x - 2}{x^2 - 2x + 2}$$

Also correct is: 
$$f'(x) = 0 \iff  2x - 2 = 0 \iff x = 1 \;\;\text{and}\;\; x^2 - 2x + 2 \neq 0$$

The only remaining task is to determine whether $x = 1$ gives a maximum or a minimum value $f(1).$

Comment: did that cover both A) and B) of the question, or just A)?

Comment: Well that's easier than i thought, i had no idea how to do it, but this can be easily memorised and applied to different numbers easily ( i think...i hope )

Comment: @Sami: Thanks! I think the question mark in my avatar looks good in a Santa cap! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Been doing a lot of derivative problems lately :-) +1